# How to remove insufficient memory error in ROS openCV?

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to make an image of a chess board with opencv and ROS but it's giving the error: the image which I am uploading [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey0KO.png) contains
the screenshot of the command prompt with an error.

and the link contains code.

I tried to make an image of a chessboard via ROS and openCV but it stars giving error while starting node that makes the image and publishes it.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc , char **argv){
    ros::init(argc , argv ,"cb_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n("~");
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
    image_transport::Publisher pub_image_raw;
    int x=argv[1];
    int y=argv[2];
    int z=argv[3];
    //int d=y/z;
    unsigned char color =0;

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr frame;
    cv::Mat img(x,y,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++){
        color=~color;
        for (int j=0;j<y;j++){
            cv::Mat ROI=frame -> image(Rect(i,j));
            ROI.setTo(cv::Scalar(180,180,180));
            color=~color;
        }
    } 

    pub_image_raw =it.advertise("image" , 1);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    while(ros::ok()){
        pub_image_raw.publish(frame ->toImageMsg());
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey0KO.png

Comment: There is no link to code. That said, you do not want a link to code.  All code links do for you is collect downvotes. You do not want to post images of code. Same deal.  The hatred is because links rot and images are hard to search and compile. You want to craft a [mcve] that reproduces a single problem. If creating the MCVE doesn't reveal the bug and the solution to you, you post the MCVE. Personally, I'm not clicking the image because there's little I can do with it, and there is no damn way I'm downloading anonymous files from an anonymous dropbox onto my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at that huge memory allocation request.
Where does it come from?

I would say this is because of

```
int x=argv[1];
```

You should convert a `string` to `int` instead of assigning a memory address into integer.

If the type of `argv` is `char **` then what will be the type of `argv[1]`?